# get value from multiple inputs with same name, Input Fields Dynamically with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post, input

I've got a form where I can add more inputs by a button

```
$("#inputs").click(function(){
$("#posicion").append('<div><div class="span4"><input type="text" name="nameInput[]" required ></div> <div class="span4"><input type="text" name="unidad[]" required ></div>');});
```

how can I get the values if the number of elements can increment dynamically?

I tried this:

```
$name = $_POST['nameInput'];
$unidad = $_POST['unidad'];

foreach( $name as $key => $nam ) 
{
   //method to insert in mysql by medoo
   $form_field = $database->insert("form_field",[
    "name_template" => $form,
    "name" => $nam,
    "unidad" => $unidad['key']
    ]);
}
```

but obviously this code is wrong because the elements can increment, they aren't static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it something like this, since there seems to be equal numbers of name as unidad

```
$name = $_POST['nameInput'];
$unidad = $_POST['unidad'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
   $form_field = $database->insert("form_field",[
    "name_template" => $form,
    "name" => $name[$i],
    "unidad" => $unidad[$i]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify keys so that you can associate nameInput with unidad. You can use jQuery to increment a value, create a random string, etc.

```
$("#posicion").append('<div><div class="span4"><input type="text" name="nameInput[' + someIncrementedValue + ']" required ></div> <div class="span4"><input type="text" name="unidad[' + someIncrementedValue + ']" required ></div>');});
```